# winreg.OpenKey throws filenotfound error for existing registry keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, registry, winreg

I am facing difficulties in reading a registry key created by my software. However with the same code, I am able to read other keys.

```
installdir = winreg.OpenKey(
                            winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
                            "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MediaPlayer\\Player\\Extensions\\Types"
                            ) #this works perfect
#installdir1 = winreg.OpenKey(
                              winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                             "SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\MyEvent\\IS"
                             ) #this gives Filenotfound error

# list values owned by this registry key
try:
    i = 0
    while 1:
        name, value, type = winreg.EnumValue(installdir, i)
        print (repr(name))
        i += 1
except WindowsError:
    print ("Bot donf")
value, type = winreg.QueryValueEx(installdir, "10")
print("user is", repr(value))

value, type = winreg.QueryValueEx(winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\MyEvent\\IS"), "v2")
print("user is", repr(value))
```

Traceback shows

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python_scripts/myclass.py", line 32, in <module>
    value, type = winreg.QueryValueEx(winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\MyEvent\\IS"), "v2")
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

However Windows reg query is able to retrieve the value set.

```
#reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyEvent\IS /v v2

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyEvent\IS
v2    REG_DWORD    0x12
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: edited the typo in req query statement. But that should not a problem anyways

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are 2 views of the registry. There is the 32-bit registry view and the 64-bit registry view. By default and in most cases, 32-bit applications will only see the the 32-bit registry view and 64-bit applications will only see the 64-bit registry view.

The other view can be accessed by using the KEY_WOW64_64KEY or the KEY_WOW64_32KEY access flags.

If you are running 32-bit python and your key is part of the 64-bit registry view, you should use something like this to open your key:

```
winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\MyEvent\\IS", access=winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
```

If you are running 64-bit python and your key is part of the 32-bit registry view, you should use something like this to open your key:

```
winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\MyEvent\\IS", access=winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY)
```

If you know the key is always part of the same view, adding the proper `KEY_WOW64_*` access flag will ensure that it works no matter what your python architecture is.

In the most generic case, if you have variable python architecture and you do not know in advance in which view the key will be, you can try finding the key in your current view and try the other view next. It could look something like this:

```
try:
    key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\MyEvent\\IS")
except FileNotFoundError:
    import platform

    bitness = platform.architecture()[0]
    if bitness == '32bit':
        other_view_flag = winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY
    elif bitness == '64bit':
        other_view_flag = winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY

    try:
        key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\MyEvent\\IS", access=winreg.KEY_READ | other_view_flag)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        '''
        We really could not find the key in both views.
        '''
```

For more information, check out [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: The beauty of this answer is that it was written correctly 2 years ago and has still not been edited, even now. Good job @Remy Roy

Comment: Awesome answer!! Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you.  adding _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY helped accessing "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSBuild\\ToolsVersions\\4.0""