# Python import error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes', after power outage

Tags: python, module, pip

There was a power outage in my area while i was working on a python script.After this happened, there was an error when i tried to import numpy.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

In Pycharm,Project-> Settings ->Interpreter ,the package list is empty.
Also, `pip install` produces this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, src_prefix
  File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 17, in <module>
    USER_CACHE_DIR = appdirs.user_cache_dir("pip")
  File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 38, in user_cache_dir
    path = os.path.normpath(_get_win_folder("CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA"))
  File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 194, in _get_win_folder_from_registry
    import _winreg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_winreg'
```

Everything was working as expected before this incident.What could have changed due to power outage?
How can i fix this this?

Comment: Something must be wrong with your Python install - winreg is builtin to python 3.

Comment: If that's the case ,why everything was fine before power outage?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a question very similar yours.  Maybe it could help you:

[importError: no module named _winreg python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320761/importerror-no-module-named-winreg-python3)

**As it says in the _winreg documentation, it has been renamed to winreg in Python 3.0. You should run the [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-to3) tool if you're converting code that was written for Python 2.x.**

Comment: I ran 2to3 tool so as to modify appdirs.py (_winreg -->winreg) but it produces a new error :
  `File "C:\Users\soc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 206, in _get_win_folder_from_registry
    directory, _type = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, shell_folder_name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] `

Comment: are you running 32-bit python and your key is part of the 64-bit registry view,?  or  are you running 64-bit python and your key is part of the 32-bit registry?

Comment: very good tips here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932831/winreg-openkey-throws-filenotfound-error-for-existing-registry-keys

Comment: No luck so far using the code from the link you posted.