# winreg.SetValueEx() for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE does not create key

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to set registry keys based on values stored in a JSON object.  I have no trouble creating keys in HKEY_LOCAL_USER.  Anything I try to create in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE doesn't get created.  The keys fail to create when running the command prompt with and without admin permissions.  Running Python 3.8.

```
from winreg import *
import ctypes, json, sys, time

#Determine the version of PDM and the branch location.
settingsData = 'EPDM_Vault_settings.txt'
solidworksVersion = 'TEST'
branch = '02'
pdmConfig = solidworksVersion + '_' + branch  #Used to select settings from EPDM_Vault_settings.txt

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

def set_reg(key, subKey, name, regType, value):
    try:
        openKey=CreateKey(key, subKey)
        SetValueEx(openKey, name, 0, regType, value)
        CloseKey(openKey)
        return False

    except WindowsError:
        print("\n**** error creating key for "  + str(key) + ' > ' + str(subKey) + ' > ' + str(name) + ' > ' + str(regType) + ' > ' + str(value) + ' : ' + str(WindowsError))
        return True

def get_key(v):
    switcher={
        "HKEY_CURRENT_USER": HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE": HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    }
    return switcher.get(v, False)

def get_regType(v):
    switcher={
        'REG_DWORD': 4,
        'REG_SZ': 1,
    }
    return switcher.get(v, False)

def set_dataType(v, t):
    if t == 'REG_DWORD':
        return int(v)
    elif t == 'REG_SZ':
        return str(v)
    else:
        return False

def configure_settings():
    with open(settingsData) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        error = False
        for p in data[pdmConfig]:
            key = get_key(p['key'])
            subKeys = p['subKeys']
            for e in subKeys:
                subKey = e['subKey']
                settings = e['settings']
                for i in settings:
                    name = i[0]
                    regType = get_regType(i[1])
                    value = set_dataType(i[2], i[1])
                    print(key, subKey, name, regType, value)
                    if key is not False and subKey is not False and value is not False:
                        error = set_reg(key, subKey, name, regType, value)
                        print(error)
                    else:
                        error = True
                        print('False detected at ' + str(key) + ' > ' + str(subKey) + ' > ' + str(name) + ' > ' + str(regType) + ' > ' + str(value))
        if error == False:
            print('\n****Success creating registry keys for SolidWorks EPDM configuration ' + pdmConfig + '\n')
        else:
            print('\n****WARNING: Registry key creation has failed. Check for typos and errors for configuration ' + pdmConfig + ' in ' + settingsData + '.\n')
            print('****IMPORTANT: SolidWorks EPDM will not function propertly until the registry keys are created.\n')

if is_admin():
    # Code of your program here
    print('already running as admin')
    configure_settings()

else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
    print('switched to running as admin')
    configure_settings()
```

The JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "TEST_02":[
        {
            "key": "HKEY_CURRENT_USER",
            "subKeys": [
                {
                    "subKey": "Software\\SolidWorks\\Solidworks 2017\\TEST FOLDER1",
                    "settings": [
                        ["", "REG_SZ", "{ED78333F-D5DB-11D4-BD5A-00C04F019808}"]
                    ]   
                },
                {
                    "subKey": "Software\\SolidWorks\\Solidworks 2017\\TEST FOLDER2",
                    "settings": [
                        ["the reg_sz", "REG_SZ", "some\\folder\\path"],
                        ["the dword", "REG_DWORD", "123"]
                    ]   
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE",
            "subKeys": [
                {
                    "subKey": "SOFTWARE\\SolidWorks\\SOLIDWORKS 2017\\test folder",
                    "settings": [
                        ["the dword", "REG_DWORD", "123"]
                    ]   
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising.

"There are 2 views of the registry. There is the 32-bit registry view and the 64-bit registry view. By default and in most cases, 32-bit applications will only see the the 32-bit registry view and 64-bit applications will only see the 64-bit registry view."

[winreg.OpenKey throws filenotfound error for existing registry keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932831/winreg-openkey-throws-filenotfound-error-for-existing-registry-keys)